# compare list into string

Tags: c#, string, list

I need to check if the string on my list are found on the `text to search` and how many string on the list are found

this is my string to search

```
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

this is my list

```
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
industry's standard dummy
text ever since the 1500s, when
an unknown printer took a galley
```

I created a sample code

```
string longString = "word1, word2, word 3";

List<string> myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "word4", "word 2", "word 3" });

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    if (myList.Any(str => longString.Contains(str)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fail!");
    }
}
```

But it prints the `success` three times. it should be once only. How can i make this work? How can i skip the item that are already used to search the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change for cycle to:

```
   foreach (string check in myList)
            {
                if (longString.Any(str => longString.Contains(check)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("success!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("fail!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It prints success three times because your are looping in *myList*.
Try like this:

```
string longString = "word1, word2, word 3";

List<string> myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "word4", "word 2", "word 3" });

if (myList.Any(str => longString.Contains(str)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("success!");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("fail!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
if (myList.Any(str => longString.Contains(str)))
```

with

```
if (longString.Contains(myList[i]))
```

to check item by item if it exists in your string.

Your current version checks 3x if any of those items exists which is always true fore the case `word 3`

Answer (score 0):

To get the count, you can use the following:

```
string longString = "word1, word2, word 3";
List<string> myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "word4", "word 2", "word 3" });
int count = myList.Count(s => s.Any(a => longString.Contains(s)));
```